# google chart label partially outside chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

[The 100 is just displayed as 00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXMh.png)

The Y-Axis label of my chart seems to be cut off. I did some investigation and found the following code snippet in the source code:

```
<text x="14.5" y="155.4614898989899" style="cursor: default; user-select: none; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px;" fill="#757575" dx="-13.4765625px">80</text>
<text x="14.5" y="80.5" style="cursor: default; user-select: none; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px;" fill="#757575" dx="-20.21484375px">100</text>
```

Now the problem seems to be that the 100's dx is at -20.21, where-as the dx of every other label is at -13.47. When I manually change that part of the source code, the 100 shows up correctly, but since the code is generated, I have no way of doing that in my source code.

Anyone have an idea how to fix that? Would be greatly appriciated!

Edit: I tried to find a solution for that on google (both the search engine and their own documentation) and tried to find anyone here with a similar problem but sadly found nothing.

```
var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Title',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    },
    chartArea: {
        left:50
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
        format: 'MM.yy',
        gridlines: {count: 15}
      },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {color: 'none'},
        minValue: 0,
        viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow:{
            max:100,
            min:1
          }
      }
  };
```

Comment: will you please share the options used to draw the chart? you can set option `chartArea.left` to allow enough room for the labels...

Comment: @WhiteHat I tried adding chartArea.left, setting it to 20, 50, 100 - but nothing seems to change. I also included my var options in the question now.

Comment: sounds like you may be using a _Material_ chart -- there are several options that are not supported by _Material_ charts, including `chartArea.*`, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?